# Spring boot, cookies on ip address domain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, setcookie, httpcookie

My server works on localhost and my VPN address (26.185.15.150), when I make request to http://localhost:3500/login/auth, I get correctly response and cookies. When I make request to http://26.185.15.150:3500/login/auth, I don't get cookies, but I get "set-cookies" in headers, how I need fix that?
SecurityConfig

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers("/login/**", "/v3/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/image/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/unsecured").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/secured").hasAnyRole("2001", "5320")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/admin").hasRole("5320")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/info").authenticated()
        )
        .sessionManagement(c -> c.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .exceptionHandling(c -> c.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
        .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:5173");
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
    config.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

my cookies set-up

```java
public void setTokenCookies(HttpServletResponse response, JwtResponse jwtResponse) {
    Cookie refreshTokenCookie = new Cookie("jwt", jwtResponse.getJwtRefreshToken());
    refreshTokenCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
    refreshTokenCookie.setMaxAge((int) jwtRefreshTokenLifetime.toHours());
    refreshTokenCookie.setSecure(true);
    refreshTokenCookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(refreshTokenCookie);
}
```

I excpected that my http request will correctly work with ip-address, like a localhost.

Comment: can i ask you why you are building this strange kind of custom authentication and not following the authentication standards that exist?